# Ellipse as mask for a label

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mask, ellipse

I'm making a toggle button with a new design "material design" like. I have a problem with animation. I'm using an ellipse that expands and changes the color of the button where the mouse clicked. With color it works well but I want to make visible label as ellipse is over it and invisible the second one. I have an image to make it simplier to understand:

[image: Toggle Button]

so the second image shows that where the green is it stills writes "Toggled" where it should already write "Untoggled" but still where blue color is, there should be writed "Toggled" then radialy changes. I have tried to use Opacity Mask but I couldn't get it to work. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I did it animating EllipseGeometry, settings the label I want to display on top of the old one and clipping the top one to the EllipseGeometry.